# The Burnside group B(2,5) and amenability

Tags: gr.group-theory, amenability

Let $n \ge 2$, then the [Burnside group](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Burnside_group) $B(n,m) = \langle a_1, \dots , a_n \mid \forall \omega, \ \omega^m = e \rangle$ is known to be non-[amenable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amenable_group) for odd $m \ge 665$, and finite for $m = 2,3,4,6$, but its finiteness for $m=5$ is open.

*Question*: Is the Burnside group $B(2,5)$ amenable?

Comment: Most likely this is unknown.